# Why can't I use video_embed_html5 on Drupal 10?

Tags: 10

I'm trying to get past the video_embed_html5 error message while going to Drupal 10.0.1....it says it isn't supported in 10.0.1....does anyone know a workaround for this...

https://www.drupal.org/project/video_embed_html5

Comment: I downvoted this question because it doesn't meet the standards of this site. For example, it refers to an error message but does not provide the error message. Drupal 10.1 hasn't yet been released as I write this.

Comment: Sorry it is 10.0.1     incompatible module
The following module is installed, but it is incompatible with Drupal 10.0.1:
Video Embed HTML5

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a feature request for a contributed module and needs to be posted to the issue queue on drupal.org

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use that module with Drupal 10 at the time that I write this. The project has not had commits since 2020 and is not marked yet as compatible with Drupal 10. There [are automated compatibility fixes](https://www.drupal.org/project/video_embed_html5/issues/3299423) that its maintainers have not merged.

Comment: Thanks for your help